# Is it necessary that default python should be python3.6 to download anaconda for python3.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

I have installed python 3.6 but python 2.7.13 is default also I have anaconda for python 2.7.13. But I want anaconda for python 3.6 which is not default can I download it directly?

Comment: Anaconda is *its own Python distribution*. You don't even need to have another Python on your system.

Comment: I know it. But I am more comfortable in python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda2 (for python 2.7.x) and Anaconda3 (for 3.5/6) can exist side by side

edit: To use one as the default python just set the path (windows control panel->system->environment variables OR .bashrc ) to point to the one you want to use as default.  ps there is no need to include both on the path and it's probably a bad idea

Comment: after installing anaconda for python 3, python 3 has become default python version.  when i give command 'python -V'  this is the result                'Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)'                                                 before installing 'python --version' was giving 'Python 2.7.13'

Comment: In .bashrc file i added below  line at the end then problem was solved     export PATH="/home/girish/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"       i .bashrc file path for anconda2 is after anaconda3 and it is working   now python -V   is giving                      Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)          Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary that default python should be python3.6 to download anaconda for python3.6?

No, its not. You can download the version for python3.6 directly from there website: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Simply navigate to the above page and select linux.

Comment: ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 21 04:58 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

Comment: it is pointing towards python2.7 but when typing python in terminal python3.6.1 is used